# Twig how to check which template is geting rendered

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have

```
<div>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="sidebar-content white-bg">
        <div class="row border-bottom">
            {% include '/layouts/navbar.html.twig' %}
        </div>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now in this `/layouts/navbar.html.twig` theres an anchor tag,  who's `href` attribute heavily depends on which template is rendered below, for example if its the Posts template, the href should be `/posts/new`, if its the announcements template, the href should be `/announcements/new`and so on, is that even possible?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: okay, let me edit stuff

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the global variable [`_self`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#global-variables) to solve this e.g.

*main.twig*

```
{% include "foo.twig" %}
{% include "bar.twig" %}
```

*foo.twig and bar.twig*

```
<div>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="sidebar-content white-bg">
        <div class="row border-bottom">
            {% include "nav.twig" with { 'template': _self, } %}
        </div>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

*nav.twig*

```
{% set path = '' %}
{% if template == 'foo.twig' %}
    {% set path = 'path/to/foo' %}
{% elseif template == 'bar.twig' %}
    {% set path = 'path/to/bar' %}
{% endif %}

{% for i in 0..3 %}
<a href="http://www.example.com/{{ path }}/{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/l3x3ag)

Answer (score 0):

If the path is the only thing that depends on the current template, I'd modify DarkBee's example to just simply pass the path from the parent template. That way you don't need the if/else structure:

posts.twig:

```
<div>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="sidebar-content white-bg">
        <div class="row border-bottom">
            {% include "nav.twig" with { 'path': '/posts/new' } %}
        </div>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

announcements.twig:

```
<div>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="sidebar-content white-bg">
        <div class="row border-bottom">
            {% include "nav.twig" with { 'path': '/announcements/new' } %}
        </div>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

nav.twig:

```
{% for i in 0..3 %}
    <a href="http://www.example.com/{{ path }}/{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```